# Drag data from VB6 application to WPF application

Tags: wpf, vb6

I am trying to drag a node of a TreeView in a VB6 application to the window of a separate WPF application. The `DragEnter` event is not firing in the target window. What steps can I take to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more information to help with a solution. Do you have access to the source code of both applications? What code have you tried, and what steps have you taken to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Have you tried something ? If Yes, kindly post here.

Comment: Have you set the AllowDrop property = True in the target?

Comment: I didn't get much help on this online. all i'm getting on VB.NET only and it is not relavent to my query :(

Comment: Yes, AllowDrop property is true on target (WPF window)

Comment: What control is the drop target?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but **IF** you're trying to drag over a panel element you need to have a background defined.

From MSDN,

> Panel elements do not receive mouse or stylus events if a Background is not defined. If you need to handle mouse or stylus events but do not want a background for your Panel, use Transparent.

You can read the complete post here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background.aspx